# Scheduling remote access

Tags: remote-access, scheduling, remote-desktop

I need a software for scheduling of remote access to my computer, so that many people are able to access it in a day, one or few hours at a time.

This may be done by changing pass-codes every hour and sending a new pass-code to every person who is scheduled for remote-access. However, I would like zero or very-little manual intervention since I want to do it for months and years.

Does such a solution exist out-of-the-box?
Can other popular software like Teamviewer be adapted to do this?
Is there any free software that can be adapted to do this?

Preferably Windows, but Linux will also do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I have found [Zoho Assist](https://www.zoho.com/assist/), a part of the [Zoho Business Suite](https://www.zoho.com/).

Zoho Assist is a free software for both commercial and personal use and it gives all the common functionalities of Desktop Sharing softwares including File Sharing, Remote Chat, Unattended Access, etc.

Apart from all that, it also has the functionality of scheduling remote sessions, sending invite emails and reminders automatically.

Posting it here so that it may be helpful to others.